# SpringBoot behind Proxy works with Undertow but not with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, proxy, undertow

I build an authorization service with SpringBoot behind a Proxy (at the moment Apache, will be Nginx later).
The service handles authentication (delegated to google, facebook,..) and issues JWTs in return.

The problem: with tomcat as container the redirect after successful authentication is to http://example.com. With undertow all is fine (https://example.com)

In Apache I have set

```
ProxyPass /auth http://localhost:8080/auth
ProxyPassReverse /auth http://localhost:8080/auth

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

In the springboot app (application.yaml)

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

Any idea what I can do to make it work with tomcat as well?
You can find the full code (except for the application.yml as it holds the oauth secrets at the moment) [on github](https://github.com/andymel123/auth-service).

Thanks in advance for any idea!

Answer (score 1):

The embedded Tomcat container in Spring Boot does not support forward headers out of the box. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6232. I lost quite some time on this.